# Как объединить ветки в git

Tags: git, github

Я случайно создал новую ветку через checkout и закоммитился в нее. В этом коммите все самые актуальные изменения, как мне перенести их в главную ветку, чтобы потом с этой одной веткой работать? P.S. Сорри за нубский вопрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Edit 1**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из главной ветки выполнить: `git merge vasha-vetka`

Comment: Добавил скриншот. Были неразрешенные конфликты, я их разрешил, сделал merge, но оно до сих пор в ту же второстепенную ветку лезет. И говорит, что теперь еще больше неразрешенных конфликтов

Comment: @dmitrykozyr на скиншоте вы сделали не то, что вам посоветовали в ответе